# I'm trying to use @keyframes to animate the background-color of an element but it's not working in Atom. What's the problem?

Tags: css, atom-editor

I'm new to coding and I'm learning how to use HTML and CSS. I downloaded Atom and I'm practicing on it. I'm trying to use the @keyframes function to animate the background-color of my square element but it doesn't seem to work on my web-browser (Firefox). I don't know what am I doing wrong.

image of the code:
[image: image of the code]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please type-in the relevant code snippets in your question instead of posting a link to the screenshot

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), showcasing the code in the question **itself**, rather than simply linking to an image containing it. Being able to copy the code helps us to debug it much faster. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using prefixes for crossbrowser support.
You can use a tool sutch as https://autoprefixer.github.io/
Autoprefixer is a PostCSS plugin which parse your CSS and add vendor prefixes.